# Eclipse (Error retrieving parent for item )

Tags: android, eclipse

I have been creating a android project for college. My teacher insists that we use eclipse i dont know why. It works fine in school but when i try use it at home i have noting but problem. I have been trying to fix this problem with two days now .My target API is 19

Thank you

[image]

And the console

```html
X:\Users\yawlhead91\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:79: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] 
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] X:\Users\yawlhead91\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:80: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] 
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] X:\Users\yawlhead91\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:118: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] 
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] X:\Users\yawlhead91\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:120: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] 
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] X:\Users\yawlhead91\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:121: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] 
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] X:\Users\yawlhead91\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:119: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] 
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] X:\Users\yawlhead91\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:116: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] 
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] X:\Users\yawlhead91\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:117: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] 
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] X:\Users\yawlhead91\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:155: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] 
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] X:\Users\yawlhead91\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:157: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] 
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] X:\Users\yawlhead91\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:158: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] 
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] X:\Users\yawlhead91\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:156: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] 
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] X:\Users\yawlhead91\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:153: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] 
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] X:\Users\yawlhead91\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:154: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] 
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] X:\Users\yawlhead91\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:192: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] 
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] X:\Users\yawlhead91\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:194: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] 
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] X:\Users\yawlhead91\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:195: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] 
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] X:\Users\yawlhead91\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:193: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] 
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] X:\Users\yawlhead91\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:190: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] 
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7] X:\Users\yawlhead91\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:191: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2015-02-17 15:06:53 - appcompat_v7]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling your application with Appcompat, then you must compile with API 21. So, change Your project->properties->Android->Project Build Target is API 21. also upgrade your buildToolsversion to latest one if you haven't. this will solve your problem. 
Hope this helps.:)